# Forward incoming connection to another server, but forward the connection IP address as well

Tags: linux, iptables, java, forwarding, ip-forwarding

I have two Linux servers. I need to forward the incoming connection from server A (1.1.1.1:25565) to server B (2.2.2.2:25598) (as an example). I've tried multiple iptables rules, with partial success. The problem is the fact that the IP is not forwarded.

**As an example, I have a Minecraft server. When there is a connection, it forwards me from 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2, however, the IP that players have is not their network IP, but server A IP (1.1.1.1 in the current example). Would it be possible to somehow forward the connected IP as well?**

If that is not possible, is there a possibility that I send a packet with the connection so I can inform the game-server of what IP player is using and make the server change it from Server A IP to real Connection IP (like [this](https://github.com/TCPShield/RealIP/tree/1.8) plugin does)? From what I saw using it, it just splits the incoming connection packet and gets the connection IP, port and timestamp. Does anyone know how?

**Rules that I tried:**

```
# Rule 1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25568 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:30026
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
# Rule 2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25599 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:30026
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 30026 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1
# Rule 3
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 12222 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.2:30026
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 2.2.2.2 --dport 30026 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Don't look too much at ports, I know those are not the same at every command but those do not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your objective by setting `default` route on `2.2.2.2` to `1.1.1.1` and then removing the `POSTROUTING` `MASQUERADE`/`SNAT` rules from your IPTables rules.

However, this means that all access to `2.2.2.2` must happen via `1.1.1.1`.

The reason you see modified IP addresses is the `SNAT` / `MASQUERADE` rule. This replaces IP packet source address with `1.1.1.1`, and is required when `2.2.2.2` has other default route than `1.1.1.1`.